# Why can't firefox automatically access the https of my domain that's a reverse proxy through caddy?

Tags: firefox, server, https, caddy, caddyfile

I'm trying to take a server I'm running and use a reverse proxy to use my domain to specifically access it. I have done this via caddy, which worked easily with the command `caddy reverse-proxy --from website.com --to:8096`. It gives no error and when I type in website.com to any browser other than firefox it works fine, but when I use it in firefox it just hangs loading and eventually gives up saying connection was reset. When I run `curl -v website.com` I get the following results:

```
 * Rebuilt URL to: website.com/
 * Trying 11.111.111.11...
 * TCP_NODELAY set
 * Connected to website.com (11.111.111.11) port 80 (#0)
 > GET / HTTP/1.1
 > Host: website.com
 > User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
 > Accept: */*
 >
 * Empty reply from server
 * Connection #0 to host website.com left intact
 curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

When I run `curl -v https://website.com` it works totally normally and finds the certificate and everything. Any guidance for how I can change the running caddy to fix this?

I expected firefox to load the server when I simply put in `website.com` but it appears I have to put in `https://website.com` or else it just hangs.